# Meaning of 'sphere of'

Tags: meaning, idioms

> who attempted to make sense of every **sphere of** social life

Comment: http://www.google.com/images?q=sphere of

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Sphere* here is another word for domain or area.

> **2** an area of activity, interest, or expertise : *his new wife's skill in the domestic sphere.*
>   • a section of society or an aspect of life distinguished and unified by a particular characteristic : *political reforms to match those in the economic*

From the NOAD.